# Where can I download Powershell 2.0 for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have spent the better part of a day hunting the Internet looking forr a way to download Powershell 2.0 to my already Win7 environment. Windows 7 is supposed to come with PS 2.0 however - I have 1.0.

How do you upgrade Powershell when there is no download made specifically for Windows 7?

Comment: It's weird that your Windows 7 has the version 1.0 when by default it has to have version 2.0. Any idea how this happened? Anyway just to confirm try running the command $psversiontable. If this command gives a result, you have version 2.0.

Answer (score 18):

I suspect that you really have 2.0. The 2.0 version installs in a directory named 1.0 which often causes this confusion. In a PS session type:

```
$host.version
```

And I suspect that you will see:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out the top link to download it:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd772288

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell 2.0 ships with Windows 7 in the box.

> Version 2.0 is integrated with Windows
>   7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 and is
>   released for Windows XP with Service
>   Pack 3, Windows Server 2003 with
>   Service Pack 2 and Windows Vista with
>   Service Pack 1.

[Quoted from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell)